# Mongoose: TypeError: mongoose.connection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to MongoDB database using mongoose ODM but I am getting an error stating that:
`TypeError: mongoose.connection is not a function`

The mongoose function:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = function connection() {
  try {
    const connectionParams = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedToplogy: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    };
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, connectionParams);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};
```

The index.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connection = require("./DB/db");

connection();

const conn = mongoose.connection();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no mongoose.connection() function in the docs
[mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

alse you already made the connection in the mongoose function file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connection = require("./DB/db");

connection();

const conn = mongoose.connection(); // mongoose.connect()
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = function connection() {
  try {
    const connectionParams = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedToplogy: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    };
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, connectionParams); //here you made the connection
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
```

Comment: Here are the docs for mongoose.connection
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.connection